# In function main: undefined reference to exec

Tags: c, gcc, exec

I came across [this page](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/macros/ExecExamples.txt),
and I made this file

```c
#include <unistd.h> 
int main(void) {
  exec("ls");
  return 0;
}
```

However compiling it gives me this message

```
$ cc foo.c
undefined reference to `exec'
```

Is that page just bogus? Out of date? What is going on here?

Comment: What do you mean by "running" it? Show the command line

Comment: There's nothing like `exec()` in linux. There's execl, execv,etc. which are called `exec()` family of functions. Refer: `man 2 exec`

Comment: For your reference (`man 3 exec`): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html The latter is C. What your link shows is Java (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: the link you referenced lists Java examples... perhaps you're looking for http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html, which I just realized was referenced in the previous comments ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is not bogus. However, the code referenced per the [link provided](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/macros/ExecExamples.txt) is actually Java, as the site refers to the ImageJ program, an "Image Processing and Analysis" Application. See [here](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/).

Answer (score 6):

You need to use one of the family of "exec" functions. i.e. one of:

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
int execle(const char *path, const char *arg,..., char * const envp[]);
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
int execvpe(const char *file, char *const argv[],
```

The manual page [exec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) will tell you of their usage. Perhaps

```
execl("/bin/sh", "-c", "ls");
```

Alternatively write `ls` using `opendir`, `readdir` and `closedir`

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `system()`?

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void)
{
  system("ls");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system` and` exec` are not the same.

Comment: @askmish, there is nothing called `exec` in C, POSIX ...

Comment: yes, I understand there's nothing called `exec()`, but the `system` call is not what `exec` family of fucntions do

Comment: @askmish, and there is nothing in the exec family that doesn't requires a second parameter, so I guess OP is trying to execute a command, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: ok, it was a guess then.

Answer (score 2):

The page you came across is about `Java` language, not `C`. If you want to compile it, use Java compiler. If you want similar functionality in C, use one of the suggestions in other answers.