# use file as an input to a compiled c program

Tags: c, file, compilation, operating-system, system-calls

In my program i get to 2 paths, one is a path of a directory which contains all kinds of files.
Whenever I find a c file I compile it.
The second path is of an input txt file.
lets say something like this:

```
home/dvir/workspace/assignment1/students/  -(directory)
home/dvir/workspace/tests/input1.txt/ -(input txt file)
```

here is part of my code:

```
void listdir(const char *name, int indent)
{
    char path[80];
    char cmd[4096 + 2*80];

    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
            printf("%*s[%s]\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
            listdir(path, indent + 2);
        } else {
            printf("%*s- %s\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name); 
            snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "gcc -c %s -o %s.o", path, path);
            if (system(cmd) == 0) {
                printf("Compiled %s to %s.o\n", path, path);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

It goes recursivly over the directory and compiles all the files, I saved the input.txt directory in a char array and called it input.
now lets assume a have a c program I compiles and got the ashly.c.o file.
how can I run this program using the txt file as an input?(and how do I actually get access to that compiled program?)
for example:
let's say the ashly.c.o gets 2 numbers from the user and multiples them.
I want to use the input.txt file to be these 2 numbers 
and save the output as a new txt file.(so that I can read it latter) 
I have found some of[this](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-use-txt-file-as-command-line-input-in-c-language) answers but in my case I don't want to use freopen() function (just open) and I need I a way to access the compiled file from my program...
Any  help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to re-invent [make](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/make.1.html) ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you are asking but as far as I can tell you have not generated any executable program yet. You need to link the .o files together (or in case each c-file is a full program, you need to compile without the -c option)

Comment: You typically cannot run .o files. But you could make a library out of them, then `dlopen()`it, `dlsym()`-link the functions provide by the single .o which made it into the library and call these functions.

Comment: Perhaps you might want [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s

Answer (score 0):

`fork` and `exec` may do what you want.

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    int fd = open("/path/to/your/input", O_RDONLY);
    dup2(fd, 0);
    // execl or so
    exec("/path/to/the/created.o", ...);
}
```

Comment: could you please explain a little bit on how it works?

Comment: After gcc compiles the file (I guess the `-c` option should be dropped), fork() and exec() would create a new process that execute the .o file just compiled. See also [redirect-exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605130/redirecting-exec-output-to-a-buffer-or-file). `stdin` was redirected to the input file by `dup2` before `exec` (I didn't know whether you've decided to use `stdin` as input, drop that line if it was not the case). More information on `fork` and `exec` may be found on APUE, CSAPP or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099663/how-to-correctly-use-fork-exec-wait).

Comment: thank you,I do understand the idea better now, One more thing,I keep on getting the warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exec’  ,although i did include  unistd.h.nDo you have any idea on what may be the reason?(I tried to compile the code without changing anything)

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` may help (but if linker doesn't throw an error, the program would run despite of the warning).

Comment: I dont know if it's the linker but the program throws /tmp/ccUPN2ER.o: In function `main':
program.c:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `exec'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I forgot to clarify that `exec` is not a function but a family of functions, see [exec-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339617/in-function-main-undefined-reference-to-exec) and choose one. I would fix my code.